# ¿Cómo muestro solo los 5 últimos carácteres de una consulta MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

¡Hola amigos! Preseto un problema y es el siguiente:

**Tengo un Token de esta magnitud:**

0df784678f277798b5752efcc4c7292b

**Pero quiero que quede así:**

7292b

De antemano agradezco sus respuestas.

*Este es mi código PHP:*

```
<?php
     $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
        $resultados = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT token FROM usuarios WHERE id = $idUsuario");
        while($consul = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){
            echo $consul['token'];}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes cambiar un poco tu query para obtener los últimos 5 caracteres de tu columna token:

```
<?php
     $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
        $resultados = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT RIGHT(token,5) as token FROM usuarios WHERE id = $idUsuario");
        while($consul = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){
            echo $consul['token'];}
    ?>
```

RIGHT es un método que pide dos argumentos: la columna de la que obtendrá el valor, y un número que le indica cuántos caracteres contando por la izquierda debe recuperar. un saludo! :D

Answer (score 3):

Usa la función **`SUBSTRING()`** la cual requiere:

- La cadena o columna de la cual quieres obtener una determinada parte
- Un número que puede ser tanto positivo como negativo, el cual indica cuantos elementos o posiciones va a recorrer

  - Si el número es positivo entonces empieza de izquierda a derecha
  - Si el número es negativo entonces empieza desde la derecha a la izquierda

Consulta:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('0df784678f277798b5752efcc4c7292b', -5) AS Seleccion;
```

Dando como resultado:

```
Seleccion
7292b
```